# Division by $n$ in elliptic curves

Tags: computational-complexity, elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb F_{p^m}$ be an arbitrary elliptic curve over the Galois field $\mathbb F_{p^m}$, and let $$[n]^{-1}(P)\cap E(\mathbb F_{p^m})=\{Q\in E(\mathbb F_{p^m})\mid nQ=P\}.$$ Also let $N=\#E(\mathbb F_{p^m})$. Is the following claim true?

If $\gcd(n,N)=1$, then the only point in $[n]^{-1}(P)\cap E(\mathbb F_{p^m})$ is $(n^{-1} \bmod N)P$.

If this claim is evident, why are powerful programs such as the MAGMA  Computational Algebra System unable to compute this point in acceptable time?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking whether multiplication by $n$ in a finite abelian group of order prime to $n$ is bijective. The answer is yes, but the question is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: Multiplication by $n$ is a bijection on any finite group of order prime to $n$.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  The question of why it takes so long to compute $Q$ is on topic.  The answer is that computing $\#E$ is nontrivial (it's polynomial time but the algorithm is not obvious and the exponent of $\log p^m$ is large enough to noticeably slow the calculation).  The alternative technique of solving the equations for $Q$ directly is not feasible except when $n$ is a product of small primes, because it requires finding a solution of a polynomial of degree $l^2$ for each prime factor $l \mid n$.

Comment: Dear Elkies, thanks for your good comment. Yes, exactly. In programs like MAGMA  for many $E$ we can easily compute $\#E$ while computing $divisionPoints(P,n)$ is infeasible.

Comment: In that case, either *DivisionPoints* is defined to return all division points over the algebraic closure or you've found something that can be improved in a future release of Magma.  Meanwhile you can write your own *UniqueDivisionPoint* that tests whether $\gcd(\#E,n)=1$ and if so computes the unique preimage over the ground field.

Comment: Now that the question has been reopened, it should be answered by
somebody who (unlike me) knows Magma well enough to tell which if either
of those two explanations is correct.

Comment: From the Magma documentation:
 "DivisionPoints(P, n) : PtEll, RngIntElt -> [ PtEll ]

    Given a point P on an elliptic curve E and an integer n, this function returns the sequence of all points Q on E such that P = nQ holds. If there are no such points then an empty sequence is returned. "

Comment: "DivisionPoints" does not seem to be defined in the package files of the Magma distribution, so we cannot see what it does. But I would assume that it tries to find all the $n$-division points of $P$ directly, without first checking (or computing) the group order.

Comment: Testing this with a random point $P$ on a random curve $E$ over ${\mathbb F}_{101}$, it looks like the time complexity is roughly cubic in $n$ (~11 seconds for $n = 1600$ on my laptop, for example). This would be fairly consistent with the assumption that Magma solves equations of degree $n^2$.

Comment: @MeysamGhahramani : What I meant is the actual time taken by Magma when calling DivisionPoints($P$, $n$). Of course, assuming hat $N = \#E({\mathbb F}_q)$ is known and computing $mP$, where $mn \equiv 1 \bmod N$, will take time polynomial in $\log q$ (i.e., constant time when $q$ and $E$ are fixed).

Comment: It is interesting that in MAGMA DivisionPoints(P, n)=DivisionPoints(P, n (mod N)) but them running times are not comparable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not speaking for the Magma group.

Even though Magma tries to provide the best (i.e., most efficient)
algorithms, it is very hard to make sure that all possible cases are
taken care of. From experiments with Magma's DivisionPoint function,
it looks like the shortcut you propose is not implemented.
I would recommend that you
[contact the Magma 
group](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/contact/) and suggest to include the shortcut in the implementation.
Including a link to this MO question in your message might also be helpful.

To deal with your problem right away, write your own function, e.g.,

```
function myDivisionPoints(pt, n)
  N := #Parent(pt);
  g, m := XGCD(n, N);
  pt1 := m*pt;
  if g eq 1 then return [pt1]; else return DivisionPoints(pt1, g); end if;
end function;
```

Judging from timing "N := #E;" twice in a row, Magma caches the group order
after it was computed, so the first line in the function body will not
recompute N every time the function is called with a point on the same
curve (but just fetch the cached value).

Comment: Dear Michael, I contacted the Magma group and explained this problem. Thanks for your good answer.